# Can I make a macro that takes the active cell's value and adds it to the end of a hyperlink, then follow said link

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

So I want to be able to go to a website who's link is "exampleURL.com/"+"value/string in active cell". The example URL doesn't change.

For example, let's say that the text in the selected cell is 123456. What I need is a macro that will take "123456" and put it on the end of "exampleURL.com/" to create "exampleURL.com/123456" and then follow that 
link.
Note: I would prefer not to change the cell value into a hyperlink, just to be able select the cell with 123456, press "Ctrl"+"l" and then my browser opens on the URL "exampleURL.com/123456"

As you may be able to tell, I am very inexperienced with VBA, so apologies if this isn't possible.

Comment: You could probably do this with the [`Worksheet_SelectionChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange) event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may like to try this code. It sets up a hyperlink in your worksheet and then follows it. Designate the cell by setting its address in the Constant *Target*.

```
Sub FollowHyperlink()
    ' 009

    Const Url       As String = "https://stackoverflow.com"
    Const Target    As String = "A15"       ' the cell where the hyperlink will be created
    Dim Page        As String               ' URL page

    Page = Selection.Cells(1).Value
    Range(Target).ClearContents
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range(Target), Url & "/" & Page
    Range(Target).Hyperlinks(1).Follow
End Sub
```

Comment: You wizard, you prophet, you exceptional being. May your harvest be plentiful!